# ng-repeat is only working to iterate over List and not Iterable or Set

Tags: angularjs, dart, angular-dart

It seems to be impossible to iterate over anything else than List with ng-repeat.

For instance, strangely the following code does not work:

```
<span ng-repeat="i in [1, 2, 3].toSet()>{{i}}</span>
```

The exception is thrown at package:angular/directive/ng_repeat.dart:126:8:

```
type '_LinkedHashSet' is not a subtype of type 'List'
```

It seems very restrictive to limit the ng-repead to proper List.
It that possible to have ng-repeat iterating over any iterable and not just List.

Oliver

Comment: Why do you want to use Set? can you describe?

Comment: A set does not defined clearly the order of its elements and if the ordering is time dependent or indeterminate, then I would rather not have my list change with every `$digest` loop iteration. Besides, there is no `Iterable` interface in Javascript, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Ok, I did not want to use Set, I wanted to use a generated iterable: myList.where((x) => myfilter(x) and to make it work I add to recreate a list: myList.where((x) => myfilter(x)).toList(). Concerning the set, the set could be an ordered set so it could make sense. Are we suppose to create a list each time we are using ng-repeat?

Answer (score 3):

It is a known limitation (https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/292), mainly because `ng-repeat` relies on `[]` operator, which `Iterable` does not support. That said, angular could internally convert `Iterable` to `List`, making it easier for the user.